# Error when String value is passed to angular service

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a Rest end point which returns the employee name as String.

```
@GetMapping("/employeeNameForOnboard/{employeeId}")
    public String getEmployeeNameForOnboard(@PathVariable String employeeId) {
           String employeeName =  onboardSearchService.getEmployeeName(employeeId);
           return employeeName;
    }
```

My Angular Service :

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    Authorization:
      'Basic ' +
      btoa('test:test'),
  }),
};


getEmployeeName(employeeId: String) {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(
  `    ${baseUrl}employeeNameForOnboard/${employeeId}`,
      httpOptions
   );
 }
```

Error:

Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com", error: {…} }

error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: "Ram, Ravishekar" }

error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

text: "Ram, Ravishekar"

Changed the end point to this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/employeeNameForOnboard/{employeeId}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> getEmployeeNameForOnboard(@PathVariable String employeeId) {
        EmployeeDetailsTO employeeName =  onboardSearchService.getEmployeeName(employeeId);
        return new ResponseEntity(employeeName,HttpStatus.OK);
}


public class EmployeeDetailsTO {
private String emailId;
private String name;
public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}
public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public EmployeeDetailsTO(String emailId, String name) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
    this.name = name;
}

public EmployeeDetailsTO(){}

}
```

Model class in angular :

```
export interface EmployeeDetails {
    emailId: string;
    name: string;   
}
```

Getting this error now on spring side:

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

And Getting this error on angular side:

Object { headers: {…}, status: 406, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com: 406 OK", error: null }
​
error: null
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
}
​
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com: 406 OK"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 406
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com"

Comment: Please check my edited answer

Comment: you need to pass Accept: application/JSON header to accept JSON response. the content-type header is more about telling the service that is the format of your request, not your desired response.

Answer (score 0):

When you work in Angular by default your endpoint expect JSON and not plain text. I think you have to return JSON Object

Please check if your class is annotated with:

```
@RestController()
```

Now you need to change the @GetMapping. It should be:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/employeeNameForOnboard/{employeeId}", produces = "application/json")
```

Then you should not return just String from the method `getEmployeeNameForOnboard` but you have to return :

```
ResponseEntity<MyModel>
```

Your method should look something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/employeeNameForOnboard/{employeeId}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<MyModel> getEmployeeNameForOnboard(@PathVariable String employeeId) {
       String employeeName =  onboardSearchService.getEmployeeName(employeeId);
       MyModel result = new MyModel(employeeName); 
       return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

By the way in Angular you also need to have class MyModel with the same properties so they can me mapped. The you use this class to work with the endpoint.

---

This is answer to your edit question.

Please change your Angular Service to:

```
const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
   'Accept':'application/json', // not 'text/plain',
   Authorization:
      'Basic ' +
       btoa('test:test'),
   }),
};
```

Comment: content-type is the request header to tell the media type of request it has nothing to do with the response. accept: application/json is the accepted response  media type

Comment: @HarishBarma Yes you are right. I update my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:7025/employeeNameForOnboard/example@gmail.com", error: {…} }

From the above error, I understood that your error block is being executed though you receive 200 success response.
I see that 'ok: false' in your error message which is triggering the error block.
Since the backend springboot is returning json body and and angular interpretor is not handling it properly.

I see you have defined headers in http options. Add one more header responseType: 'text' and in  return this.httpClient.get****(
    `${baseUrl}employeeNameForOnboard/${employeeId}`,
httpOptions   ***remove the 'any' from get<any> and add responseType header .***

So final solution will be .

getEmployeeName(employeeId: String) {
return this.httpClient.get(
    `${baseUrl}employeeNameForOnboard/${employeeId}`,{
httpOptions,
responseType:'text' }
);
}